# Git: git fetch <branch> ends in "xxx/xxx does not appear to be a git repository"

Tags: git, github, branch, git-fetch

I'm having problems on fetching one specific branch from my remote repo.

If I do git **branch -a** the output is:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10
...
```

and that is ok, all my branches are in remote but as soon as I do

```
git fetch origin/release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10
```

I receive:

```
fatal: 'origin/release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm the owner of the repo and I have rights on it and if I do:

```
git remote -v
```

the output is:

```
origin  https://xxxm@xxx.org/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.git (fetch)
origin  https://xxx@xxx.org/xxxxx/xxxxxxx.git (push)
```

So 'origin' is pointing to where it have to.

At this point **I'm stuck on being able to fetch one specific branch** (haven't tried fetch --all yet)

Something to add just in case:

Not sure it may have something to do with it, but just in case and if it is of any help, I can add that I pushed two very big files by mistake yesterday and then removed them both following 'BFG Repo Cleaner' instructions (https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/). They're easy to follow and my big unwanted files dissapeared from local and remote/history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `git fetch` command takes zero, one, or two-or-more arguments:

- `git fetch`: call up the *default* remote (usually `origin`) and fetch everything
- `git fetch remote`: call up the *named* remote.  Usually you *must* use `origin` here.
- `git fetch remote branch1 ... branchN`: call up the *named* remote, and when it lists its branches, pick out only the specific *named* branches.

You're trying to use the last of these three forms but making two separate mistakes:

1. You *must* provide the name of the remote, in this case, `origin`.
2. The `origin/*` names in *your* Git are the result of your Git renaming *their* Git's *branch* names so they don't conflict with your own branch names.

Hence what you want is:

```
git fetch origin release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10
```

which calls up *their* Git, asks them about *their* `release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10` branch, and updates *your* `origin/release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10` name.

#### If you find this confusing, rest assured, it *is* confusing

This whole thing about where the slashes go, and when, is confusing until you realize two things:

- The *third* word—the plain `origin` part—isn't a *branch* name (`master`, `release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10`) and isn't a *remote-tracking* name (`origin/master`, `origin/release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10`).  It's a third kind of name, a *remote* name.
- *Branch* names like `master` and `release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10` are private to each repository,  You can *see* theirs with `git fetch` but your `git fetch` *renames* them to make your *remote-tracking names* like `origin/release/2.0.23175_BBDDv10`.

So you always have to remember to ask, when you have a branch name, *whose* branch name is it: yours, or theirs?  Well, you only really have to remember this when you *connect* both Gits, with `git push`, `git fetch`, or `git pull` (which runs `git fetch`):

- With `git push`, you will have your Git ask their Git to set one of their *branch* names.  You will send them some commit(s) as needed, then your Git will ask them: *Please set ______ (branch-name) to ______ (commit-hash ID), if that's OK.*  (Using `git push --force` turns this polite request into a command.)
- With `git fetch`, you will have their Git look at their *branch* names, get any new commits *from* them into your own Git, and then update your *remote-tracking* (`origin/*`) names.
- `git pull` runs `git fetch`, so it does the same as `git fetch`.  (After `git fetch` finishes successfully, `git pull` runs a second Git command, usually `git merge`.  I generally advise *avoiding* `git pull` until you really understand how both `git fetch` *and* the second Git command work, as each step on its own is confusing enough, but this is a personal choice you should make yourself.)

#### Aside

Here's a simple rule for most Git users: never use `git fetch --all`.

(It doesn't *break* anything, but it does not mean what people think it means.)

(The rule for advanced Git users is *don't use it yet*.  Wait, no, that's the rule for [optimization](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9196301). )

Comment: What a great and very good explained answer @torek. I appreciate you effort and help very much. I will put on this as soon as possible and I'll read your answer again more carefully and follow your instructions, and of course I'll let you know and most likely mark your answer as correct. Thnaks again for your "masterclass" on git fetch :)